# Getting a check log error on publish in SmartFace app studio

Tags: smartface.io

I am trying to publish the android app from SmartFace app studio and it is giving me an error to check logs. I am not sure where to find these logs. Publish to iOS works fine. Also I verified the android SDK is found in Project Details tab.

I have attached the screenshots here

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This kind of publishing error can be caused by many factors. The ones that I know of are:

1. node.js that comes with Smartface is outdated, so you have to update it mannualy by going to its site and installing the latest version.
2. Sometimes Smartface says Java is found but it's not, so writing the correct directory could fix the issue.

Comment: I downloaded the latest version of node from https://nodejs.org/en/ and also verified android sdk and java path. Still the same error.
If someone can let me know the path to log file